# Is there any way to record a video of website using headless Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I know there is a way to make screenshots, using many available APIs, such as Puppeteer

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

but what about recording videos? my goal is to capture a CSS animation into an mp4 file.

Or am i doing it all wrong, are there better tools for that on the server side?

Comment: Why aren't you just using a regular screen recording software?

Comment: It has to work on a backend, as part of a backend application (video editor, as part of 'render' function). The generated video will then be consumed by ffmpeg and become part of a rendered output video.

Answer (score 2):

For recording video with audio, try `puppeteer-stream`:

https://github.com/Flam3rboy/puppeteer-stream

Comment: I tried it and the output video is excluding the javascript-based animation effects.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-recorder

Something like this can work, it takes lots of screenshots and stitches them together

Comment: This option only records images, not audio. Any idea to record audio/video?

Comment: As of today, it is not working and crashing the browser!