# Stream a website to a mp4 (rendering html to a mp4)

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I am trying to composite a website (which contains JavaScript and as a result is updating regularly) with a video feed.  My goal is to do it on virtual hosted Linux server (my plan is to use Ubuntu, but I am flexible) - I am not interested in solutions utilizing OBS or the like as my solution would be headless.

The problem I am facing is how to output the website to a video stream from a command line.

The site I want to capture is https://vscore.ch/home and I would like to render it in a way that I can feed it to ffmpeg where I can composite it with the live game video that is being delivered via RTMP.

Comment: This is possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261175/is-there-any-way-to-record-a-video-of-website-using-headless-chrome - I wasn't aware that headless chrome was a thing!

Comment: Found a full npm that supports this... https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-screen-recorder

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use [this puppeteer plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-mass-screenshots) and stream those screenshots, or parse them into a video and stream that.

Comment: I've looked at puppeteer-stream, but it requires headful (not headless) operation...  Screenshots seems like a lot of work to then generate an MP4 from, but it could be interesting.

Comment: @Muppet1856 Read the description, the plugin works in headless